# Graphql API pagination issue

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I would like to fetch all repositories from a specific user. In case the user has a lot of repositories, it would be better to use pagination.

As far as I can see here, we are allowed to pass first and last property. But what if I want to get repositories between 10-20?

```
query MyQuery {
  user(login: "someuser") {
    repositories(first:10" ) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can access here => https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub GraphQL API uses the popular [cursor-based pagination pattern](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/#pagination-and-edges).  Each record has an opaque, id-like cursor.  Return the cursor from the query. Use it as input to the next query.  [Apollo Client has tools](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/) to help with this.

```
{
  repository(name: "apollo-client", owner: "apollographql") {
    issues(last: 10, after: "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOP2I0Sw==") {
      edges {
        node {
          createdAt
          title
        }
        cursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get up to 100 nodes, but then you need to use pagination, which is done by getting `pageInfo` for `hasNextPage` and `endCursor`

e.g. I can get my first 100 repos with:

```
query ReposByUser {
  user(login: "cpswan") {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the response will end with:

```json
        "pageInfo": {
          "hasNextPage": true,
          "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOFdXRZQ=="
        }
```

So I can then get the next page with:

```
query ReposByUser {
  user(login: "cpswan") {
    repositories(first: 100 after: "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOFdXRZQ==") {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which this time ends with this telling me there are no further pages:

```json
        "pageInfo": {
          "hasNextPage": false,
          "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOGb3wAQ=="
        }
```

Comment: To see the previous page, I guess I need to use it before. But hasNextPage and hasPreviousPage are returning false. I am using startCursor for it

Comment: If both `hasNextPage` and `hasPreviousPage` are false then that implies that `totalCount` is lower than the max page limit (100 in my example).

In most cases it makes little difference whether to start with the first 100 and page to the next, or with the last 100 and page to the previous.

Comment: Tip: you can pass `after: null` to fetch the first page. Helpful when your GQL query is fixed and always contains the parameter name.